# Radio button with input textbox on it using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

I'd like to create a radio button with a textbox on it, so a user can select the button and enter his own text. This is what I've been doing (using twitter's bootstrap), but the text doesn't show up in the box:

```html
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" id="btn-group-id">
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" value="Label"> Enter your own label
    <input type="text" name="other_reason" />
  </label>
</div>
```

How can I alter this so the user can click on the radio button and enter text in an input textbox on top of the button?

Comment: The label element may contain at most one button, input, meter, output, progress, select, or textarea descendant.

Comment: You don't give very much information about what you're actually trying to accomplish. From your code, it looks to me like it's a choice for "Other" which lets you then enter your own text. In that case, the radio button should _enable_ a previously disabled text box. A textbox is not _"on"_ a radio button. Trying your snippet, it lets me enter and edit text just fine, whether or not the radio button has been selected, and the text shows up in the textbox as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Just use place holder, instead of writing out ide of input box.

```html
      <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" id="btn-group-id">
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
          <input type="radio" name="options" value="Label" > 
          <input type="text" name="other_reason" placeholder="Enter your own label"/>
        </label>
      </div>
```

Comment: The label element may contain at most one button, input, meter, output, progress, select, or textarea descendant.

Comment: This is the same problem--I'm unable to edit the text input box

Comment: I guess, I didn't get your point mostly. Since I can edit text input box. my understanding on your problem may be wrong!